# streaming audio + video to the browser

Tags: c++, audio, video, browser, containers

For a project of mine (in C++, Linux) I'm looking for a lightweight method (CPU wise, something that also runs on raspberry pi alike systems without hardware acceleration) for streaming video + audio to the webbrowser.

For video only, mjpeg works on all major browsers.

According to https://caniuse.com/#search=mpeg4 I should mpeg4 for video + audio, unfortunately mpeg4 is not lightweight.
An alternative could be the matroska container but on apple that is only supported with vp8, also kind of heavy(?).

So I'm looking for suggestions what to use. Something that is supported on linux, mac and windows with the major browsers for that platform. Bandwidth usage is less important.

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on whether you are looking for the server side or the client side.

In other words, taking a raspberry PI as an example, whether you want the PI to be the streaming server that is serving the video or the host which is playing back the video.

Taking PI as an example, for the case where the PI is the streaming server, then you have several options.

You can set up the PI as a simple static file server and serve the MP4 that way, or you can use a number of available open source and 3rd party streaming server solutions that allow a PI provide media server functionality. Some examples:

- ReadyMedia (used to be MiniDLNA) - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ReadyMedia
- PLEX - http://www.rasplex.com/get-started/rasplex-installers.html
- Kodi based OSMC - https://osmc.tv/download/

For the case where the PI is on the play back side, then there are native players which are documented on the PI documentation (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/omxplayer.md):

- omxplayer /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/test.h264

For the case where you will have a camera on the device or attached to the device, the camera solution itself will typically support encoding into a commonly available format.

For example the Raspberry PI camera solution supports h.264 encoding, leveraging the encoding HW on the PI -see here for more info:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md

To understand how this impacts your solution performance requirements, its worth looking at how the video is encoded and transported. The steps at a high level are:

- raw pixels bitmap captured for each frame
- raw pixels encoded (e.g. h.264 encoded)
- encoded video stream packaged (sometimes called 'muxed') into container with audio streams, subtitles etc (e.g. mp4 container)
- for more advanced multi user streaming services, ABR streaming may be used also and the container broken into 'chunks' or segments for streaming (on iOS using HLS streaming format).

Diagrammatically, roughly like this:

[image]

The most processor intensive step above is usually the encoding step - as a very rough rule of thumb, and assuming you are looking for a high quality video stream, the more compression the encoder provides to make the file or stream size smaller, the higher the overhead.

If we again take PI as an example, the PI has HW support for H.264 encoding and the default Camera SW will make use of this support to do the encoding for you as efficiently as possible - i.e. with minimal processing overhead.

The most efficient solution for you will likely depend on the codecs that  that your particular device supports 'natively' - i.e. leveraging the HW on the device. H.264 is a very common codec and it also has the advantage that most of the client devices playing back the video will also typically support it (at this time).

If you mean that you don't want to use this native support when you say 'without HW acceleration' then you will likely be looking for the lowest processing overhead codec you can find. This will likely not be the one with the best compression or the the one most widely supported but there is some research into codecs which are designed specifically to have low processing - e.g.

- https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7079872

This Netflix technical blog is also worth looking at:

- https://netflixtechblog.com/performance-comparison-of-video-coding-standards-an-adaptive-streaming-perspective-d45d0183ca95

And finally, just to add a last complication (sorry!) it can be the case that a solution which is low overhead for encoding is actually high overhead for decoding, so you may need to check that a selected solution is also applicable for your end user device.

Comment: Hi, I am looking for the server side. Also, as described mpeg4 is not an option as it would be too cpu intensive on small systems.

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden  Can you describe what you want in a bit mote detail? All of the above will run on a PI and will stream MP4 files. Streaming MP4 is not particularly CPU intensive so I suspect you may be actually capturing and encoding, or maybe transcoding the video on your device which would be a different solution than a simple static streaming server.

Comment: Oh right, yes, I want to encode video and then stream it. So I record it from the rpi native camera, or via an usb camera, or retrieve it from some other source (depending on the system on which it runs), then apply filters, encode it and stream it.

Comment: Ok - added some more info in the answer above. Many small footprint devices like a PI already have native support for video encoding so leveraging what is available on the device is nearly always the most power and processor friendly way to go.